# Where can I ask this question related to a "QA Automation project"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> It's been a question since long time. Everytime code goes for review
>   there are different opinion from different senior
>   developers/coders/QA. And every other person fights for its own
>   opinion.
>
> Here are some of "Code review":
>
> 1. There should be single HTML identifier.`CSS Selector`, `id`, `name`, `xpath` or whatever, but choose only one across the project
> 2. It should be `xpath` only across the project
> 3. Use name and `id` only, as they are fast and readable
> 4. You can use whatever is easily available i.e. sometimes use `xpath`, and then sometimes use `Css selector` etc etc
>
> Which one is best practice in terms of speedy execution of Automation
>   tests and managing Object repositories? Plus you can point in Code
>   Review meetings that this is why I am using it.
>
> If it depends which tools you are using, as of now I am using WATIR
>   (Ruby+cucumber) and previously I was using JAVA.

This question was earlier posted by me on **Code Review SE** but there it got closed due to off-topic, not so sure where to post so posting here.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)**

Comment: None of my comments were meant to be negative, only to be helpful. If that wasn't conveyed clearly I apologize.

Comment: @rene This world is just like that, "You are advocate of your emotions, but other's is just joke/BS". Dont laugh, I am not getting sentimental here, you apologised, so I am just sharing a fact of matter.

Comment: I downvoted because...

Answer (score 6):

I guess this question is primarily opinion based, since you actually ask "who is right?", or "which is best?". That brings in a rather big part of subjectivity into your question.

That question shouldn't be asked here, since most tech QA sites are open to relatively objective questions only.